# wxpython global variables

Tags: python, wxpython

im trying to create global variables of wx.Panel, wx.Button, and wx.TextCtrl,

so that i can "Edit" them in different functions

coming from a java background i thought maybe "panel = wx.Panel()" outside all functions might work but i get an error saying i need to send arguments to it, and i dont know what those arguments should be.

disclaimer: i'm a python noobie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes the arguments [defined by the wxPanel constructor](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxpanel.html#wxpanelctor).

Comment: thank you, i had tried that before, the problem was that i was declaring the parent (frame) locally in a function, and the panel globally, i thought i could just declare an empty panel somehow and pass the arguments later, but i guess thats not possible, so i just made the frame global aswell and now it works. Thanks for your time